# Block outgoing connections on RHEL7/CentOS7 with firewalld?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, redhat, firewalld

RHEL7/CentOS7 features a new `firewalld` firewall service, that replaces the `iptables service` (both of which use `iptables` tool to interact with kernel's Netfilter underneath).

`firewalld` can be easily tuned to block incoming traffic, but [as noted by Thomas Woerner](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/firewalld-users/2013-February/000053.html) 1,5 years ago "limiting outgoing traffic is not possible with firewalld in a simple way at the moment". And as far as I can see the situation hasn't changed since then. Or has it? Is there any way to block outgoing traffic with `firewalld`? If not are there any other "standard" ways (on RHEL7 distro) of blocking outgoing traffic except manually adding rules through `iptables` tool?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't find any option in that nice GUI, but it is possible via direct interface

To enable only outgoing port 80:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -j DROP
```

This will add it to permanent rules, not the runtime rules.
You will need to reload permanent rules so they become runtime rules.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

to display permanent rules

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --get-all-rules
```

to display runtime rules

```
firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
```

Comment: How does one achieve this using the actual rich-rule language?

Comment: @Casey By my understanding, rich rules are strictly used for INPUT chains.

Comment: I presume the above rules work only for `ipv4` (iptables).  It may be desirable to have similar rules for `ipv6` (for ip6tables) or `eb` (for ebtables).

Comment: Also, this killed my SSH connection to the server!  See user253068's answer for how to retain established connections.

Answer (score 13):

After asking the same question myself, and with some tinkering, I've gathered some nice rules for restricting outgoing traffic to HTTP/HTTPS and DNS queries:

Allow established connections:

```sh
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow HTTP:

```sh
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow HTTPS:

```sh
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow for DNS queries:

```sh
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Deny everything else:

```sh
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 2 -j DROP
```

It might be a good idea to test first by omitting the '--permanent' argument.

I am by no means an expert, but this seems to work fine by me :)

Comment: At some point you may find it useful to remove the rules.  Removing single direct rules seems tricky, but for a sledgehammer, `firewall-cmd [--permanent] --direct --remove-rules ipv4 filter OUTPUT` will do a bulk remove.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the GUI; I think you find this under "**Direct Configuration**". To access it you have to select it in "**View**". I could be wrong.

**Side note**

To delete rules; you have to exit and then reenter.