# Block outgoing connections on Centos 7 with firewalld

Tags: firewall, centos7, firewalld, firewall-cmd

I'm having following rules :

```
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Everything works fine, then I'm adding following direct rules :

```
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 2 -j DROP
```

Using following sample command :

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I'm unable to do wget or connecting to MySQL in port 3306

I'm already follow the same question and problem at [Block outgoing connections on RHEL7/CentOS7 with firewalld?](https://serverfault.com/questions/618164/block-outgoing-connections-on-rhel7-centos7-with-firewalld) and still the same problem.

The only different is at command for "--dport 80" and "--dport=80", which is I think the same.

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block outgoing connections on RHEL7/CentOS7 with firewalld?](http://serverfault.com/questions/618164/block-outgoing-connections-on-rhel7-centos7-with-firewalld)

Comment: The only different is command for "--dport 80" and "--dport=80", which is I think the same. Tried them, still having the same problem