# Blocking ALL outgoing traffic Using firewalld to dedicated network subnets?

Tags: centos, firewall, redhat, firewalld, rules

I have several RHEL7/CentOS7 servers on which I need to block *all* OUTGOING traffic to dedicated machines or dedicated network subnets e.g. CIDR 168.192.10.0/24.

For the moment I tried with `firewall-cmd` but was not lucky. Most of the posts I saw were using `iptables` but I would rather prefer a solution based on `firewalld`.

I already tried to base my solution on these two topics [Block outgoing connections...](https://serverfault.com/questions/618164/block-outgoing-connections-on-rhel7-centos7-with-firewalld) and [Block outgoing connections on Centos 7 with firewalld](https://serverfault.com/questions/791204/block-outgoing-connections-on-centos-7-with-firewalld) but somehow my rules must be wrong since I still can open an http connection to the server.

Current `firewalld`rules (no rules defined)

```
public (active)
    target: default
    icmp-block-inversion: no
    interfaces: eth0
    sources:
    services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
    ports:
    protocols:
    masquerade: no
    forward-ports:
    sourceports:
    icmp-blocks:
    rich rules:
```

Let's assume server source IP of the server is 168.192.18.56. Next, the rules I tried to define (also with `--permanent`

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 168.192.10.0/24 -j REJECT 
firewall-cmd  --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="168.192.18.56" destination address=168.192.10.0/24 reject'
```

I also tried with *DROP* action. The current rules are

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" destination address="192.168.10.0/24" log prefix="dropped" level="debug" limit value="20/m" drop
```

Now not sure if I must reload `firewalld`? In this case, I would make the rules permanent.

My misunderstanding is now that

- assume on 192.168.10.30 a web server is running.
- I can ping e.g. 192.168.10.30
- I can also open an HTTP connection `wget  192.168.10.30` and get the `index.html` back
- I also can ping each machine in the blocked subnets, but perhaps this needs a special rule, I thought by blocking all traffic ICMP would also be blocked

I would appreciate knowing what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I can also reproduce this behavior.. I'm not sure if the rich rules can apply to outgoing traffic (though with the source/dest distinction it seems like they should). Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: It might be just a typo and not relevant to your issue, but you have some mixture of 192.168.*.* and 168.192.*.* here.